# "ImportError: No module named deserialize" when launching ur5_bringup.launch

Tags: ros, roslaunch, ros-industrial, universal-robot, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I attempt to run the command `roslaunch ur_bringup ur5_bringup.launch robot_ip:=172.22.22.2`, I get the following output:

```
... logging to /home/rkeatin3/.ros/log/5d470f28-5de0-11e4-aa81-fc4dd43d9838/roslaunch-dscl-rosstation-02-13666.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://dscl-rosstation-02:45140/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /robot_description
 * /robot_ip_address
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /tf2_buffer_server/buffer_size

NODES
  /
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/state_publisher)
    tf2_buffer_server (tf2_ros/buffer_server)
    ur_driver (ur_driver/driver.py)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [13683]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 5d470f28-5de0-11e4-aa81-fc4dd43d9838
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [13696]
started core service [/rosout]
process[robot_state_publisher-2]: started with pid [13708]
process[ur_driver-3]: started with pid [13726]
process[tf2_buffer_server-4]: started with pid [13727]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/ur_driver/driver.py", line 19, in <module>
    from deserialize import RobotState, RobotMode
ImportError: No module named deserialize
[ur_driver-3] process has died [pid 13726, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/ur_driver/driver.py 172.22.22.2 __name:=ur_driver __log:=/home/rkeatin3/.ros/log/5d470f28-5de0-11e4-aa81-fc4dd43d9838/ur_driver-3.log].
log file: /home/rkeatin3/.ros/log/5d470f28-5de0-11e4-aa81-fc4dd43d9838/ur_driver-3*.log
```

I've been unable to find any posts with the same answer. I checked the roslaunch log file, but it doesn't have any more useful information. Any ideas?

Edit: I'm using hydro, installed from debs.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196020/%22importerror:-no-module-named-deserialize%22-when-launching-ur5_bringup.launch/) by [rkeatin3](https://answers.ros.org/users/19735/rkeatin3/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2014-10-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-10-27**:
ROS version, driver version, from source, from debs, etc (I know some of it is visible in your console copy/paste, but still).

**Comment by [rkeatin3](https://answers.ros.org/users/19735/rkeatin3/) on 2014-10-27**:
I'm not sure what you mean by driver version, but all of my packages should be up-to-date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't give you any solution right now, but I've created an issue at the `universal_robot` repository. See [universal_robot/issues/134](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/issues/134).

---

Edit: just proxying for the Github issue:

this is a known issue with the currently released (v1.0.3) Hydro debs and will be fixed in the next release. The `hydro-devel` branch already contains the fix, so if you build the `universal_robot` repository from source, things should start working again for you.

Alternatively, you could temporarily add the `ur_driver` directory to your `$PYTHONPATH`:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ur_driver/
```

after sourcing your `setup.bash` (don't forget to remove this once fixed debs have been released).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1